# Vacuous truth and empty set properties

Tags: logic

I have a flaw in my reasoning, could you help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

To proof that $\emptyset$ is closed under addition we need to evaluate the following logical statement:
$$
\forall x,y \in \emptyset: Q(x,y)
$$
where $Q(x,y)$ is "$x+y \in \emptyset $"

We can transform this into a conditional statement like so:

$$
\forall x,y \in A:P(x,y)\implies Q(x,y)
$$
where $A$ is a non-empty set with at least two elements and $P(x,y)$ is "$x,y \in \emptyset$".
Here we can see that the first statement will always be false since $\emptyset$ has no elements and then by conditional logic this whole statement evaluates to true and so we conclude that $\emptyset$ is closed under addition. This is a vacuous truth.

But can we not use the same conditional logic to proof that $\emptyset$ is not closed under addition by using $R(x,y)$ to be "$x+y \notin \emptyset$"?
$$
\forall x,y \in A:P(x,y)\implies R(x,y)
$$

Since the antecedent $P(x,y)$ will always be false the whole statement will always evaluate to true and then we can conclude that $\emptyset$ is not closed under addition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For addition not to be closed on the empty set, you would need to show $\exists \,x,y \in \emptyset: x+y \notin \emptyset$.

This is not a consequence of the vacuous truth $\forall x,y \in \emptyset: x+y \notin \emptyset$, so there is no contradiction with the other vacuous truth $\forall x,y \in \emptyset: x+y \in \emptyset$. Assuming you have a suitable definition of addition, it remains the case that addition *is* closed on the empty set.

Comment: @monkey_learning_maths For closure of a function on a set, you need to show *all* applications of the function to the elements work.  Showing at least *one* works would be an example, but would not be sufficient (and in the case of the empty set neither necessary nor possible)

Comment: Now I understood everything, sorry for my confusion. I think it all stems from my wrong and quick definition of "not closed under addition". Thanks a lot!

Comment: @monkey_learning_maths To clarify, the proposition "not closed under addition" $\exists x, y \in \varnothing \colon x + y \notin \varnothing$ is the negation of the proposition "closed under addition" $\forall x, y \in \varnothing \colon x + y \in \varnothing$ by De Morgan's laws.

Answer (score 1):

You have almost "reinvented" Proof By Contradiction !

We want to know whether $P$ is true or not.

You have :
$ P \rightarrow Q $
$ P \rightarrow R $

You know that :
$Q = \lnot R$ [ Equivalently $R = \lnot Q$ ]

Putting these together , we have a Contradiction.

Hence , we know that $P$ can not be true !

Example :

$M$ is the Empty Set of Martians.

$P$ : "Martians Exist" : $\exists m \in M$

$Q$ : "All Martians are born on Mars" : $\forall m \in M : BornOnMars(m)$
$R$ : "All Martians are not born on Mars" : $\forall m \in M : \lnot BornOnMars(m)$

$Q = \lnot R$ [ Equivalently $R = \lnot Q$ ]

$P \rightarrow Q$
$P \rightarrow R$

We can conclude ( Proof By Contradiction ) that "Martians Exist" is not true : $P$ is not true.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understand your reasoning and I can see that P is not true. But what I really do not understand is how P -> Q is used to proof that the empty set is closed under addition, because since P is false (there are no elements in the empty set) we can not use P -> Q nor P -> R to say whether the empty set is closed or not under addition. I have updated my question and added a link to the post where my confusion originated.